# oracle to_char() different language shows garbage

Tags: sql, oracle

In my oracle function there is a query that is used to make an XML output with the required values. Everything works fine. If I store a Bengali/Bangla name in a column then it returns to my website perfectly, but the problem arises when I want to see the date in Bengali/Bangla. The following query has 2 columns as date. I have used to_char() to format them.

```
SELECT XMLAGG(XMLElement("employee", 
                           XMLForest(bp.ebasp_id AS "ebasp_id",
                                     bp.b_ebasp_name AS "ebasp_name",
                                     bp.ebasp_gender AS "ebasp_gender",
                                     bp.ebasp_category AS "ebasp_category",
                                     bp.ebasp_region_type AS "ebasp_region_type",
                                     bp.ebasp_region_name AS "ebasp_region_name",
                                     bp.ebasp_sub_region AS "ebasp_sub_region",
                                     bp.ebasp_location AS "ebasp_location",
                                     bp.b_ebasp_designation AS "ebasp_designation",
                                     to_char(bp.ebasp_date_of_joining,'DD-MM-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=bangla') AS "ebasp_date_of_joining",
                                     bp.ebasp_grade AS "ebasp_grade",
                                     bp.ebasp_slab AS "ebasp_slab",
                                     bp.ebasp_basic AS "ebasp_basic",
                                     bp.ebasp_photo_upload AS "ebasp_photo_upload",
                                     to_char(bp.ebasp_created_on, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=bangla') AS "ebasp_created_on",
                                     bp.ebasp_created_by AS "ebasp_created_by")))
  INTO xmlReturn
  FROM tbl_emp_basic_profile bp
  WHERE bp.ebasp_designation=sent_designation
```

The returned date value is : 07-02-2016 03:43:29 ������
This value is shown in Mozilla. But name shows perfectly in Bangla. What is the problem? Besides, I have tried using to_nchar();

Comment: That's down to the client's rendering of the Unicode characters/codepoints. In SQL Developer I see `পূর্বাহ্ন` for the AM marker using my current sysdate. Maybe your web server is mangling it somehow, or the browser can't handle it properly, or the XML document is declaring an encoding that doesn't support the codepoints.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using [an ISO 8601 timestamp format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) in your XML, i.e. HH24 instead of HH and the AM/PM marker?

Comment: Yes, the client wants 12 hour format. Well maybe the problem is in web service, I thought the problem is in my code.

Comment: Have you tried other browsers? [Maybe you're seeing this Firefox font issue?](http://bdallinfo.com/bangla-font-problem-in-browsers/)